# What is the preferred way to include error messages in Markdown?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, markdown

When I have a question that displays an error message from somewhere, is it better to place that error message inside a code markup block or a quote markup block?

It seems like more people are doing it with code markup blocks, but that doesn't really make sense as error messages are not code; rather, they are *quotes* from whatever entity generated the message.

Comment: Note that in a quote you'd need to manually escape any `<` (and `>`) character.

Comment: and `#` @Arjan; you get random headings otherwise.

Comment: I'm surprised there is no official recommendation for this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It has nothing to do with whether the error is code or not. You should use the option which renders the error message in the most readable manner. For me, this has normally been as quoted text rather than code but that is not true for every situation.

For instance, if we take this Java exception marked up as code it looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Intro.<init>(Intro.java:15)
    at Intro.main(Intro.java:58)
```

and as a quote like this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(Unknown Source)
>       at Intro.(Intro.java:15)
>       at Intro.main(Intro.java:58)

The quote does not look good.

However, looking at this Oracle error marked up as code

```
ERROR at line 1: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."TMP_BEN_TEST"."A") ORA-02063: preceding line from DB1 ORA-06512: at line 18
```

It is more difficult to read; far better as a quote:

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into
>   ("SCHEMA"."TMP_BEN_TEST"."A") ORA-02063: preceding line from DB1
>   ORA-06512: at line 18

Comment: As an aside: note [the different rendering on mobile](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qBs6I.png) (code blocks never show scrollbars: they are not limited in height, and have no horizontal scrollbars but wrap text instead). But *long* stack traces should be avoided anyhow.

Comment: I also wonder if screen readers might somehow interpret code blocks differently from quotes?

Comment: I've been trying to find a particularly egregious example I remember of the long stack trace art (about 150 lines long and that was the entire question) but I have a feeling I only saw it whilst voting to delete... I honestly have no idea how a screen reader might see it. You could ask the question :-).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion stacktraces look very readable when they are formatted using `python` as a language something like -

```python
your ugly error

```

This will render like - [image]

Comment: Can you explain why you think that looks good? I think it looks awful, with the random red and blue highlights on words.

Comment: It is a personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

I'd put it in a code block, but [use none as the language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to avoid funky syntax highlighting that usually just doesn't make sense:

```
<!-- language: none -->

    This is the error that isn't code but isn't a quotation
```