# Should log snipplets and firebug header dumps be wrapped in code block?

Tags: discussion, markdown, code-block, blockquote

Should the log fragments and firebug traffic dumps be wrapped in code block instead of quote block?

I was used to wrap them in quote blocks, which sounds more intuitive for me, but recently I wasn't able to post a few questions containing either log fragments about network errors or firebug dumps (mostly HTTP headers sent and received). After a few tries I've noticed the offending fragment is `localhost`. Another notice, that wrapping those with code block helped.

So actually `localhost` addresses are accepted only in code block. HTTP headers or server logs are likely to contain those. So obviously, blockquotes aren't designed to contain such content, while code blocks are.

Does it mean, that by design, the code blocks are adequate for both http headers/network traffic dumps and logs? And blockquotes should be used exclusively for quoting someone's words?

Comment: Related: [What is the preferred way to include error messages in Markdown?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165160/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-include-error-messages-in-markdown/)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards is it possible that the SE policy against formatting has changed recently, and the error messages I've got are the example of it? I don't remember having such problems in the past.

Comment: No idea Lukasz, your mention of being unable to post is the sole reason I didn't vote to close as a dupe. I would guess some checking is going on... Generally, as in the other question, use the one that makes it look best. If this is by-design then use the other.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards actually I'm unable to use blockquote in logs and headers considering network traffic, so my choice is quite limited. I'd like to know if it's done on purpose.